# sed - Remove all words except matching pattern

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, grep

I need a command in sed/awk/grep that remove all words except the patterns.

I have the input:

> **Charles Hatchett** was an English chemist who **discovered** the element **niobium**.

I need the following output:

> Charles Hatchett discovered niobium

I've found some answers in google, but I can't join all these command even in sed or grep.

Comment: `I need ...` is not a good format for an SO question. Please provide what you have tried and what isn't working.

Comment: thank you. now that explains the negatived. I also tried other command but it was so stupid and I'm embarrassed to post here.

Comment: ^^ Never mind about embarrassment. All of us started at step 0 & were at your stage at some time. But it is important to know that you have tried & not just asking for ready-made code. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through awk,

```
$ echo 'Charles Hatchett was an English chemist who discovered the element niobium.' | awk '{print $1,$2,$8,$11}'
Charles Hatchett discovered niobium.
```

If you don't want `.` at the last then try,

```
$ echo 'Charles Hatchett was an English chemist who discovered the element niobium.' | awk '{sub(/.$/,"",$11); print $1,$2,$8,$11}'
Charles Hatchett discovered niobium
```

OR

Through sed backreference,

```
$ echo 'Charles Hatchett was an English chemist who discovered the element niobium.' | sed 's/.*\(Charles Hatchett\).*\(discovered\).*\(niobium\).*/\1 \2 \3/g'
Charles Hatchett discovered niobium
```

OR

Removing some words through sed to get the expected result,

```
$ echo 'Charles Hatchett was an English chemist who discovered the element niobium.' | sed 's/was an English chemist who //g;s/the element //g;s/.$//g'
Charles Hatchett discovered niobium
```

Comment: thank you, but it's only a example, I can't determinate a position on the line. I need delete everthing except the patterns wherever they are.

Comment: the pattern that I put, in this case, "charles hatchett", "discovered" and "niobium"

Comment: so you want to remove all except the above three?

Comment: exactly, it's what I want like `sed s/was//`and all the other words, except the patterns that I showed.

Comment: @aresardido like you said.